# mybatis is not returning column value in where clause when using annotation Result and Many

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am using mybatis from spring boot version 1.3.1 and I used annotation to return nested query result, but I don't get why the column value I used in where clause are all null in the result set, although they are not empty in database.

The returned json is

[image]

The mapper is like this:

[image]

The data in db:

[image]

The bean is simple, 2 items under the main item.

```
public class TestBean {
    String id;
    String name;
    List<TestSubBean> items;
}
```

Could anyone give a hint on this?

Comment: I would guess that it's because ref_id is missing in your select statement for `getSubItemsTestByRefId`

Comment: thanks pointing that out @user2718281, I added it to the select and it's working fine now. But I still don't get why box id was not populated, it should be "A8F3E0C6F14D41CD8A3614D90F297ED7"

Answer (score 0):

Change *column = "ID"*  to *column = "id"*.
I guess that mybatis use id_test's property 'id' as parameter,and 'ID' is not a property of id_test

Comment: I changed it to `@Result(property = "items", javaType = List.class, column = "id", many = @Many(select = "getSubItemsTestByRefID"))`, but still id is not populated

Comment: @Result(property = "items", column = "id", many = @Many(select =**packageName** + "getSubItemsTestByRefID"))
Change getSubItemsTestByRefID to fullName.